# Como alterar o response Content-Type no DataSnap REST

Tags: delphi, rest, datasnap

Tenho um projeto feito a partir do `WebBroker REST`, rodando como serviço, preciso alterar o response `Cotent-Type` para `'application/json'` e por padrão o `WebBroker REST` me traz como resultado o

> Content-Type 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'

Eu altero o response acessando o método

> GetInvocationMetadata(True).ResponseContentType = 'application/json'

da classe `Data.DBXPlatform`, mas mesmo assim não resolve ele adiciona mais um `Content-Type` logo abaixo do atual.

Isso só acontece somente no `WebBroker REST`, se eu criar um projeto pelo `DataSnap Server` eu consigo normalmente. Mas eu preciso do `WebBroker REST` para acessar as informações que o cliente me manda.

Exemplo de como fazer para o problema ocorrer.

- Criar um projeto a partir do DataSnap REST Application

Na classe ServerMethods, fazer no mesmo modelo.

```
uses System.StrUtils, Data.DBXPlatform;

function TServerMethods1.EchoString(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := Value;
  GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseContentType := 'application/json';
end;
```

Com isso tempos a seguinte resposta do Header.

Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 25
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 16:41:37 GMT
Pragma: dssession=542354.126073.592372,dssessionexpires=1200000
Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma, quem usa `WebBroker REST` para um `WebService` a partir do projeto `DataSnap REST`, existe uma classe `IdCustomHTTPServer`, nessa classe contém uma função `SetHeaders`, segue a linha de código logo abaixo a ser incluída:

```
if ContentType <> '' then  
  FRawHeaders.Values['Content-Type'] := ContentType;
```

O que ele faz nessa linha de código é pegar o `ContentType` que você determinou e somente ele, o **Encoding** `charset=ISO-8859-1` ele deixa invisível, faz tudo certo, até o `Content-Lenght` ele calcula certo para mostrar o tamanho do conteúdo a ser transferido.

Para o Content-Type assumir o que você determinou, na classe WebModuleUnit1 no evento `AfterDispath` do `TWebModule`, incluir a linha de código como segue o exemplo abaixo.

```
if ResponseContentType <> '' then
  Response.ContentType := ResponseContentType;
```

Sendo que `ResponseContentType` é uma variável global vindo da classe `ServerMethods`, assim consigo controlar o que deve ser alimentado no `Content-Type`.